# JsonOptions contains SerializerSettings

Tags: c#, json

jsonoptions does not contain a definiton for serializersettings

```
    builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add<JsonExceptionFilter>();
            options.Filters.Add<RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute>();
            options.Filters.Add<LinkRewritingFilter>();
        })
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
            options.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset;
        });
```

[error part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWOfG.png)

Comment: install and use newtonsoft.json package https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm

Comment: not working, I used Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: maybe JsonSerializerOptions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Add  "AddNewtonsoftJson" in statup.cs file

Dll NuGet: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(o => 
{
    o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

This should work.